# Unit Testing with Microsoft EntityFramework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

I have a currently small personnal project that I want to start off on the right foot which means making sure that my fonctions are unit tested.
My application normally use the data context `S_ERP_DBEntities` but when testing I'd want to change the data context to `Test_S_ERP_DBEntities`.
This is what I have so far but i am really not sure. The view by default calls the default constructor which means that I'd have the right data context when not testing since the default constructor doesn't change it.

LoginViewModel.cs

```
private object dbContext = new S_ERP_DBEntities();

    public LoginViewModel(object dbEntities)
    {
        dbContext = dbEntities;
    }
```

Unittest1.cs

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var dbContext = new Test_S_ERP_DBEntities();
        var login = new LoginViewModel(dbContext);
    }
}
```

That would work but I don't know if there is a more elegant way of doing it.
Any feedback will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is actually a very common way of testing a layer, it's called [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). To make it slightly more elegant, you can have a default constructor that initializes `dbContext` to whatever it needs to be at runtime:

```
private object dbContext;

public LoginViewModel()
{
    dbContext = new S_ERP_DBEntities();
}

public LoginViewModel(object dbEntities)
{
    dbContext = dbEntities;
}
```

This way the "real" object creating an instance of this View Model won't have to worry about initializing `dbContext` and can simply use the default constructor, while your unit tests can call the overload to "inject the dependency".

As a side note, I'd change the type on `dbContext` to its actual type instead of `object`. I'm assuming you are using `object` because you have two different context types: `S_ERP_DBEntities` and `Test_S_ERP_DBEntities`. This, while works, is a code smell, since **unit tests normally don't rely on the database**. Instead of creating a different context that talks to your database for testing, you should instead **create a mocked (read: fake) instance of `S_ERP_DBEntities`** and pass that in when testing your view model. The key thing to note here is this: it is safe to assume Microsoft has already unit-tested Entity Framework, so you can safely *mock* it. See this link on [using Mock with Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx) for more information.

Comment: thanks, that answered my question very well. I'll check out the link you posted.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)